# using regexp in visual studio 2010 to find and replace attributes

Tags: regex, visual-studio

i have a regexp `(c|C)(lass)="([A-Za-z0-9_-]\s)(popup)(\s[A-Za-z0-9_-])"` that will return the class attribute with a value of popup inside.

I am having difficulty to get this to run in the visual studio 2010 find and replace. Ultimately i would like to replace the `popup` with another class name lets say `im-with-stupid`

My first issue is with running the find returning `Grouped expression is missing ')'.` My assumption is the error is caused by the `"`. **How can i escape this in the search.**

Bonus points for the replace regexp - sorry i cant get that far to make an example code yet.

Comment: My link was for the regular expressions used by VS2010 and below. VS2012 uses normal .NET regular expressions. See [Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Comment: i am not sure why you are down voting.

Comment: [so] helps those best who help themselves. I recommend you read the documentation, then ask any remaining questions.

Comment: yeah i need help with regexp i am not that good at it. That is why i posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VS2010:**

Find What:

```
  {[cC]lass="[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+ }popup{ [A-Za-z0-9_\-]+"}
```

Replace with:

```
\1im-with-stupid\2
```

Find options:

```
Use Regular expressions
```

**VS2012:**

Find What:

```
([cC]lass="\w+\s)popup(\s\w+")
```

Replace with:

```
$1im-with-stupid$2
```

Find options:

```
Use Regular expressions
```

Comment: {(c|C)lass=\"(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])*( ))*}(popup){( ([a-zA-Z0-9_\- ])*)*\"}

Comment: This is an important hint about different regex syntax in 2010 (if you search the internet, you usually get the standard .NET syntax, which only works since VS 2012).